# Firestore Security Rules - Update one specific field without providing data for the other fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm new to Firestore and it's security rules. For my project, I have some simple rules for data validation that looks like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow create, update: if
        request.resource.data.name is string &&
        request.resource.data.age is int &&
        request.resource.data.score is int;
}
```

At the moment I have only tested it on the simulator and it works fine in terms of validating the data, but the problem is for each query I have to provide data for all fields/keys mentioned in the rules. For example, if I want to update the `name` of the user, I also need to provide the `age` and `score` data.

How should I structure my rules so it's possible to update only one specific field without providing data for the other fields?

Comment: "the problem is for each query I have to provide data for all fields/keys mentioned in the rules. For example, if I want to update the name of the user, I also need to provide the age and score data" That seems unlike my experience with Firebase security rules. The `request.resource.data` is the data as it'll exist after the write operation, so unless your code is overwriting all fields, it should contain the merged fields. Can you show the code of you tested this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I haven't written any code yet, I've only tested it in the Rules Playground on the console. For both create and update, if I provide only the name data, it would give me this error: "Error: simulator.rules line [16], column [11]. Property age is undefined on object."

Comment: Did `age` exist in the existing document that you were updating? If so, that might be a bug in the playground then. I recommend testing with code, where I am quite certain **no** such bug exists.

Comment: Ah right my bad, I did the update call on a field that doesn't exist yet. Thank you, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.resource.data` variable contains the data as it'll exist after the write operation (if that succeeds), so unless your code is overwriting all fields, it should contain the merged fields of the existing document you're updating and the fields specified in the `update()` call.

If the rules playground doesn't follow these rules, that might be a bug in the playground. I recommend (also) testing with actual code, as I'm pretty certain that there's no bug there for `update` calls (as it'd lead to quite some support calls).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get) to get a field and set a default value if it doesn't exist as shown below:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow create, update: if
    request.resource.data.get("name", "") is string &&
    request.resource.data.get("age", 0) is int &&
    request.resource.data.get("score", 0) is int;
  }
}
```

Checkout [enforcing types for optional fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#enforcing_types_for_optional_fields) section in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like I missed that part in the documentation. I do think it could work, but for update query wouldn't it overwrite the data in the database with the default value?